# How to make a callable reference to a top level function from another file?

Tags: kotlin

This is valid Kotlin file:

```
fun <A> fourtyTwo(foo: A): Int = 42

val bar = listOf("candy", "chips", "drink").map(::fourtyTwo)
```

However, in my project, `fourtyTwo` is a [top level function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope) defined in **another** file.

Is there a way make a [callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) to a top level function from another file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. You need to make sure the function is imported, and then make a callable reference as always.

Comment: My bad. Thanks. Maybe it was too obvious :-)

Answer (score 1):

As said in [yole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52219651/1909634) you can call top level functions from different files by importing the function in the other file.
In your case it would resolve like so:

File A

```
fun <A> fourtyTwo(foo: A): Int = 42
```

File B

```
import fourtyTwo
val bar = listOf("candy", "chips", "drink").map(::fourtyTwo)
```

In the case where top level function is in a file declaring a foo.bar package name, your file B could look like this:

```
import foo.bar.fourtyTwo
val bar = listOf("candy", "chips", "drink").map(::fourtyTwo)
```

or like this:

```
val bar = listOf("candy", "chips", "drink").map(::foo.bar.fourtyTwo)
```

The later could be useful is calling functions with the same signature but in different packages.

Hope this helped!